# jQuery on scroll event not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to display an alert on chrome using jQuery 1.3.2 as follows:

`$(window).scroll(alert("Hello"));`

It worked a few times, but then I received an error after five scrolls saying: `TypeError: Object 100 has no method 'apply'`

So I changed it to the following: `$(window).scroll(function(){alert("Hello")});`

But this does nothing at all whatsoever. I am testing this on Chrome. Could anyone let me know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The first one would only alert on first pageload, the second one seems more correct, but if it's not working hit F12 and check the console for errors.

Comment: i didn't know jquery 1.3.2 existed

Comment: @PedroEstrada http://blog.jquery.com/2009/02/20/jquery-1-3-2-released/ :)

Comment: @adeneo I'm running it through the console.

Comment: @AkshaiShah - You did notice that that relase note was from 2009 ?

Comment: @adeneo Yeah I know :) It's not up to me sadly :(

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/minagabriel/c5UfL/

Comment: Without any other context, this question is impossible to solve. @AkshaiShah, you need to provide any errors you received or your code in a JS fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

The second code snippet you posted is the correct syntax for assigning a function to run on an event. That code works properly when I test it with a current version of jQuery. jQuery 1.3.2 is five years out of date, so I'd hazard a guess the issue is with the crazily old jQuery version you're trying to use.